# End-to-End application testing from a users standpoint

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, testing

I am looking for a good way to consistently test my web applications from the end users point of view. I have all kinds of ways to check to make sure my code is working behind the scenes. I can't count the number of times that I make a change to a piece of code, test it and it works fine and then deploy it only to have it blow up somewhere else weeks later. I have by that time forgotten the change I made that caused it to blow up. I need something that I can run every time I make a change to assure me I did not break something somewhere else.

It needs to be able to input correct and incorrect entries so that client side validation can be tested also.

Thank you,

Scott and the Dev Team

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen [this](http://gojko.net/2007/05/20/automating-web-tests-with-fitnesse-and-selenium/) technique using [fitnesse](http://www.fitnesse.org/) and [selenium](http://selenium-core.openqa.org/)?

Can't vouch for how easy it is to set up, we've looked at selenium a little and one of our test analysts is keen to integrate something like FIT/Fitnesse into our automated testing but we're not there yet.

Comment: We are also using FIT/Fitnesse with Selenium where I work and it is great. Peace of mind knowing that you didn't break anything by running the entire regression suite.

Answer (score 5):

I thin you need to investigate [Selenium](http://selenium.openqa.org/). We use it to do automated UI testing throughout our solution, and it is cross browser and cross platform.

You can use the [Selenium IDE](http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/) to record a walkthrough of your web application, and then you can either run it in the browser, or export it to various languages such as C#, and run it using NUnit. I find this is the easiest approach because I can create the basic walkthrough and then modify the code to use inputs from a file/database in order to create multiple scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Seleno](http://teststack.github.com/TestStack.Seleno/), which abstracts Selenium / Browser interaction into C# Page Objects which represent the pages of your site. More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14153528/169334).