# Functional test software/framework that covers Asp.Net Web Apps?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, testing, automated-tests, functional-testing

I recently began to use the [NexusLight](http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet/Wiki/View.aspx?title=ASP.NET%20QA), a functional test automation framework. 
Are there more frameworks that does a similar job?

Related question: [End-to-End application testing from a users standpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91703/end-to-end-application-testing-from-a-users-standpoint)

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91703/end-to-end-application-testing-from-a-users-standpoint) as well.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't really looked into NexusLight but I think [InCisif.net](http://www.incisif.net/) is supposed to provide a functional test framework as well. You could look into it.

Comment: Looks nice! I'm going to download and evaluate it.

Answer (score 1):

I test asp.net web apps for years and the only tool I use is [Watir](http://wtr.rubyforge.org/).

Answer (score 1):

VSTT 2010 should be a good bet if you are looking for functional test automation. Web Services Testing, UI testing, Biztalk testing and Data Driven Testing Support. Please look at VSTT - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee338734(v=vs.90).aspx

You can also try VSTT - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slumley/archive/2009/05/28/vsts-2010-feature-enhancements-for-web-test-playback-ui.aspx

Telerik Test Tools - http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools.aspx

Visual Studio UI Test Extensibility–Scenarios & Guiding Principles - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2011/03/28/visual-studio-ui-test-extensibility-scenarios-amp-guiding-principles.aspx

VSTS Web Test Step-by-Step Primer - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimmymay/archive/2009/02/23/vsts-web-test-step-by-step-primer-7-minute-video-by-microsoft-a-c-e-performance-engineer-chris-lundquist-with-copious-notes-screen-shots-from-your-humble-correspondent.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Found this one too:

http://www.automatedqa.com/products/testcomplete/index.asp

Unfortunately it's not free.

Answer (score 0):

Reading a [list made](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ScottHanselmans2007UltimateDeveloperAndPowerUsersToolListForWindows.aspx) by Scott Hanselman, I found these two tools:

- [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/), to automated the tests;
- [WatiN Test Recorder](http://watintestrecord.sourceforge.net/), to automate the test code generation.

From WatiN page:

> [...]WatiN (pronounced as What-in) website. Inspired by Watir  development of WatiN started in December 2005 to make a similar kind of Web Application Testing possible for the .Net languages.

And from WatiN Test Recorder:

> The purpose of the application is to generate code compatible with the WatiN  (Web Application Testing In .NET) project.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Seleno](http://teststack.github.com/TestStack.Seleno/). It uses Selenium under the bonnet but abstracts all browser automation into [Page Objects](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects), which lead to well structured and fluid C# based tests.

It is particularly well suited to ASP.NET MVC, as each Page Object can be strongly typed (using Generics) to an equivalent MVC ViewModel, leading to a consistent relationship between View, ViewModel and Page Object.

Check out some of the samples in the Seleno codebase to see this in action.